# Duplicated short description on woocomerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to change the position where the short description of a product is and move it to a custom info tap below, I managed to do that using this code:

```
// Remove short description
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

// Add short description to a custom product tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'add_custom_product_tab', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    $custom_tab = array(
        'custom_tab' =>  array(
            'title' => __( "Short description", "woocommerce" ),
            'priority' => 12,
            'callback' => 'short_description_tab_content'
        )
    );
    return array_merge( $custom_tab, $tabs );
}

// Custom product tab content
function short_description_tab_content() {
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    if ( ! $short_description ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">' . $short_description . '</div>'; // WPCS: XSS ok.
}
```

it successfully add the short description into the custom tap, but it does not remove the short description of the original place so I end up with the description duplicated in two places on the product page, what can I do?

Comment: remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 ); will remove it - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php#L54

Comment: Actually it may depend on WooCommerce version and theme, Could you please tell me which WooCommerce version and theme you are using on your website?

Comment: Hi I'm using the latest woocommerce version 6.3.1 and the Theme I'm using is Astra

Comment: OK, if you are using Astra theme with Elementor builder then below two references can help you to remove short description from single product page,

1) https://wpastra.com/customize-woocommerce-product-page/ ( if use precreated elementor template for product detail page )
2) https://wpastra.com/docs/single-product-woocommerce/

Comment: thanks I founded the solution to my problem on the second link you posted!